# Scons custom dependency scanner not called for .cpp files

Tags: scons

I have a scons project directory containing following files:

```
dep.txt
main.cpp
SConstruct
```

---

content of `SConstruct`:

```
env = Environment()

def f_scan(node, env, path):
    print("[.] Scanner invoked. -> %s" % str(node))
    return env.File(["dep.txt"])

fscan = Scanner(function = f_scan, skeys = ['.o', '.cpp'])
env.Append(SCANNERS = fscan)

env.Program('main', ['main.cpp'])
```

---

content of `main.cpp`:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    cout << 1 << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

---

content in `dep.txt` does not have any specific meaning.

---

`scons -Q` output(if dep.txt was changed after last build):

```
[.] Scanner invoked. -> main.o
g++ -o main main.o
```

`scons -Q` output(if dep.txt was not changed after last build):

```
[.] Scanner invoked. -> main.o
scons: `.' is up to date.
```

---

I am trying to implement a custom scanner for `.cpp` files. I want to add extra dependencies for all `.cpp` files on top of one that is detected by inbuilt Scanner. But I notice that scanner never called on `.cpp` files. However, it gets called correctly for `.o` files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the manpage: https://scons.org/doc/production/HTML/scons-man.html#scanner_objects

> Note that scons has a global SourceFileScanner object that is used by
> the Object, SharedObject and StaticObject builders to decide which
> scanner should be used for different file extensions. You can use the
> SourceFileScanner.add_scanner() method to add your own Scanner object
> to the SCons infrastructure that builds target programs or libraries
> from a list of source files of different types:

So if you change to:

```
env = Environment(CPPPATH=['.'])


def f_scan(node, env, path):
    print("[.] Scanner invoked. -> %s" % str(node))
    return env.File(["dep.txt"])

fscan = Scanner(f_scan)

SourceFileScanner.add_scanner('.cpp', fscan)
SourceFileScanner.add_scanner('.o', fscan)

env.Program('main', ['main.cpp'])
```

Note that you are not adding to the scanners applied to .cpp and .o, you are replacing them.

So if I create an x.h and change main.cpp to:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "x.h"

using namespace std;

int main(){
    cout << 1 << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

You will see this:

```
% python ~/devel/scons/git/as_scons/scripts/scons.py --tree=prune
scons: Reading SConscript files ...
scons: done reading SConscript files.
scons: Building targets ...
[.] Scanner invoked. -> main.o
[.] Scanner invoked. -> main.cpp
g++ -o main.o -c -I. main.cpp
[.] Scanner invoked. -> main.o
g++ -o main main.o
+-.
  +-SConstruct
  +-dep.txt
  +-main
  | +-main.o
  | | +-main.cpp
  | | +-dep.txt
  | | +-/usr/bin/g++
  | +-dep.txt
  | +-/usr/bin/g++
  +-main.cpp
  +-[main.o]
scons: done building targets.
```

Whereas without your custom scanner:

```
% python ~/devel/scons/git/as_scons/scripts/scons.py --tree=prune
scons: Reading SConscript files ...
scons: done reading SConscript files.
scons: Building targets ...
g++ -o main main.o
+-.
  +-SConstruct
  +-main
  | +-main.o
  | | +-main.cpp
  | | +-x.h
  | | +-/usr/bin/g++
  | +-/usr/bin/g++
  +-main.cpp
  +-[main.o]
  +-x.h
scons: done building targets.
```

So what you likely want is to still call the existing scanner and add your file to it:

```
env = Environment(CPPPATH=['.'])


# get existing .cpp scanner
origin_cpp_scanner = SourceFileScanner.function['.cpp']

def f_scan(node, env, path):
    filename = str(node)
    print("[.] Scanner invoked. -> %s" % filename)
    if filename.endswith('.cpp'):
        current_files = origin_cpp_scanner(node, env, path)
    else:
        current_files = []
    print("Files:%s"%[str(f) for f in current_files])
    return current_files + env.File(["dep.txt"])


fscan = Scanner(f_scan)

SourceFileScanner.add_scanner('.cpp', fscan)
SourceFileScanner.add_scanner('.o', fscan)


env.Program('main', ['main.cpp'])
```

Which then yields:

```
% python ~/devel/scons/git/as_scons/scripts/scons.py --tree=prune
scons: Reading SConscript files ...
scons: done reading SConscript files.
scons: Building targets ...
[.] Scanner invoked. -> main.o
Files:[]
[.] Scanner invoked. -> main.cpp
Files:['x.h']
g++ -o main.o -c -I. main.cpp
[.] Scanner invoked. -> main.o
Files:[]
g++ -o main main.o
+-.
  +-SConstruct
  +-dep.txt
  +-main
  | +-main.o
  | | +-main.cpp
  | | +-x.h
  | | +-dep.txt
  | | +-/usr/bin/g++
  | +-dep.txt
  | +-/usr/bin/g++
  +-main.cpp
  +-[main.o]
  +-x.h
scons: done building targets.
```